# Semantic-UI, responsive horizontal table unstackable, single line, with scroll

Tags: css, semantic-ui

This is the example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/WRXGNFlG1FWrF8rtIVU4?p=preview

You can resize the window to see what I mean:

- **Table in Desktop mode:**
  [image: Table in Desktop Mode]
- **Table in Mobile mode:**
  [image: Table in Mobile mode]

I'm using `display: block` on table. It works good on mobile mode, but not in Desktop mode, as you can see. Why?

Can we fix this small problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Media queries**

```
@media (min-width:320px)  { table { display: block; } }
@media (min-width:960px)  { table { display: table; } }
```

This is a simple example, but you could adapt the breakpoints for your specific needs.

**Table wrapper**

If you have a table that is too wide, you can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed. Resize the browser window to see the effect. Try to remove the div element and see what happens to the table.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Forked version of your example: https://plnkr.co/edit/irZUV08VdBYUemFiMiwI?p=preview

Comment: I can't wrap my table in another div because of the `attached` class...

Comment: So I would recommend the first of my two suggestions; a media query.

Comment: Yes, but with media-query is not a good solution. In the middle pixels I have the problem.